# What did Geoffrey Hinton mean when he said this?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, rnn

I was going through some lectures from the Deep Learning course that Geoffrey Hinton taught on Coursera and I came across this statement:

*"RNNs could potentially learn to implement lots of small programs that each capture a nugget of knowledge and run in parallel, interacting to produce very complicated effects."*

I have no idea what he meant nor seen/figured out any examples of this idea (and I'm sure other people are wondering too.) So if somebody would care to demonstrate, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't have the context, but I found [a longer version of the quote from Yoshua Bengio](https://ift6266h16.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/lecture-21-march-30th-2015-recurrent-neural-networks/) that's more clear: “RNN could potentially learn to implement lots of small programs, **using different subsets of its hidden states**. And each of these little programs could capture nugget of knowledge and run in parallel, interacting to produce very complicated effects.”

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220907/meaning-of-and-proof-of-rnn-can-approximate-any-algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Creating a model **is** having the computer write a small program. If you have a multi-layer network, then multiple nuggets might be interacting to produce complicated results.

That its pretty much how things like face detection work - you start with a series of really dumb "detectors" that look like basic rectangles and they combine in ways so that at the top, you're recognizing Brad Pitt.

Comment: This is not what the quote is referring to. There is a key difference in behaviour of a RNN compared to a feed forward network. A feed forward NN model can approximate any function. A recurrent NN model can approximate any algorithm.